# How to get average sales of an employee before certain sale in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime

Suppose I have a table with 3 columns: `EMPLOYEE_ID, NUM_SALES, DATE`. Simply this is the table of Employees indicating daily sales. For each row in the table, I try to compute this; average number of sales of that EMPLOYEE_ID in the last K days excluding this day.

How can I query this in MySQL? I try to group by with EMPLOYEE_ID and DATE but I cannot figure out how to find last K sales for each row.

Answer (score 1):

To select an interval of days, you can use MySQL's [`DATE_SUB()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function:

```
WHERE `date` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

This will select all records that are from the past 3 days. However, to exclude "today" from that:

```
WHERE `date` BETWEEN
     DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
     AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

After that you should be able to [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) the `employee_id` to get what you're after:

```
SELECT
    employee_id, avg(num_sales) AS avg_num_sales
FROM
    employee_table
WHERE `date` BETWEEN
     DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
     AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY
    employee_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to select items from your table, let's call it `dailysale`, by date.

Here's what you do.

```
SELECT employee_id, AVG(num_sales) AS avg_sales
  FROM dailysale
 WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
   AND date < CURDATE()
 GROUP BY employee_id
```

This uses two `WHERE` clauses to winnow down the date range you're using. `date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY` excludes all records before midnight three days ago, and `date < CURDATE()` excludes all records on or after midnight today.

You need to use `CURDATE()` rather than `NOW()` because, well, `NOW()` includes the date and the present time of day. `date < NOW()` will include today's sales, because your `date` column only records dates and not times.

If you want to list the employees in order of sales, you could add

```
 ORDER BY AVG(num_sales) DESC, employee_id
```

to the query.